# I see new datatypes in the ARC list

Tags: advantage-database-server

Can someone provide me with an updated "Advantage .NET Data Provider Data Types" list so I can map the new type names to the Advantage Client Engine Constant Name and the .Net Db Type?

Thanks,

Howard S. Edidin
Senior BizTalk Architect
Ceridian Benefit Services

Answer (score 2):

I believe the new types all map to System.String:

```
case ACE.ADS_NCHAR:
case ACE.ADS_NVARCHAR:
   return Type.GetType( "System.String" );

case ACE.ADS_NMEMO:
   return Type.GetType( "System.String" );
```

Comment: What I need is the Advantage Client Engine Constant Name for these data types. This is critical for parsing metadata. I use these in an Enumeration.

Comment: The Advantage Client Engine only uses integer constants, the ones I mentioned above (ACE.ADS_NCHAR, etc.). The text versions are self-explanatory ("nchar", "nvarchar", "nmemo").

Comment: I am not using the ACE. I am using ADO.NET to call sp_getProcedureColumns to return the TYPE_NAME.

Comment: look at the Advantage .NET Data Provider Data Types in the documentation.